# What happens when I do git pull origin master with "--rebase"

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull, pull, pull-request

Let's come to my problem .

what is the different between this 2 command , i am confused about that .

```
1. git pull origin master
2. git pull --rebase origin master
```

here what is the job of "--rebase" .
Please let me clear !

Pull everything from the remote master in the local develop and merge it? Pull everything in the local master branch and merge it?

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from [git-pull(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) man page:

> ```
>    -r, --rebase[=false|true|preserve]
>        When true, rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch
>        after fetching. If there is a remote-tracking branch corresponding
>        to the upstream branch and the upstream branch was rebased since
>        last fetched, the rebase uses that information to avoid rebasing
>        non-local changes.
>        ... continued ...
> ```